# Hashing integers to alphanumeric with no collision

Tags: algorithm, hash, mathematical-optimization

Do you know any hashing method for a long numeric string to a shorter alphanumeric? I need to obtain a unique string of max length 10 out of 3 strings with a total of 33 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot map **all possible** length 33 decimal sequences 1:1 into length 10 alphanumeric string with reasonable alphabet size (you need alphabet size 2000: `10^33 = x^10 => x~1996`)

But for **limited known set** of decimal sequences - you can calculate [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) and represent hash values in appropriate system (for example: in 36 radix using `0..9, A..Z` chars)